# Problem with gltf when importing to three.js

Tags: three.js, transparency, gltf

Im working on a project for my schoolwork and im having a problem with importing gltf file in three.js.
I make my gltf files with blender 2.9. So if i export gltf separate (+bin+textures) i can import a model with gltf loader but the problem is that textures that are meant to be transparent are not, even if i test the file on the online gltf loader they arent transparent. But if i export as embedded gltf everything works correctly on the online gltf viewer but in my project i get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise)
> error { target: img, isTrusted: true, srcElement: img, eventPhase: 0, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, returnValue: true, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, timeStamp: 768, … }

Does anyone have any idea whats wrong? I spent hours now trying different stuff and im almost sure that my node setup in blender is correct as i read some forums and also official documntation on Blender.
Or maybe is there anything i can fix with separate exported gltf to make transparency working?

Thanks

Comment: If you can share a `.blend` that follows the Blender exporter documentation but doesn't appear correctly in glTF viewers when exported, it would be worth filing a bug on https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO. For a glTF model that looks OK in a viewer but not in your code, you may need to share that code, or try asking on the forums of whatever WebGL engine you're using (https://discourse.threejs.org/ for three.js).

Comment: Also, what version of Three.js are you using? The online editor uses the latest, which is `r122`. You might have an older version in your project that may not have all the features that the editor does.

Answer (score 0):

try adding in renderer({alpha:true})
to add the posibility of transparentnes im not sure but it should work

please add your code to see if something else is wrong with code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers. I managed to fix the problem now with the separate gltf version by adding these two line to the renderer:

```
    gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
    gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Then I was able to see through the texture but only things that were part of the same object in Blender everything else was white but then i figured out it was beacause this object was one of the first to be drawn thats why i guess it took canvas white color instead of the objects in the background.
Thanks again